# Cypress: Can I use a value in the log as a string?

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, cypress-mailosaur

Currently I have my Cypress code writing out an email verification code to the log.

[image: Cypress Runner Log]

[image: Dev Tools Console]

I need to take the six numbers from this value, to be inserted into a text field as a string.

The code I have in Cypress looks like this.

[image: CypressExample.js]

And the line of code related in the feature file looks like this.

[image: CypressExample.feature]

I cannot pass the object into 'type' because it can only be a string or number.

Is there a way to take out the number element from the log to be used in the placeholderText part of the code I currently have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `email.text.codes[0]` yields an object with one key (of `value`). So I think we'll just need to [access that `value` field.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

```js
cy.get('foo')
  .type(email.text.codes[0].value);
```